# Как импортировать данные из json в html

Tags: json

Прошу сразу не пинать, я человек начинающий многое не знаю. Вопрос про то как получить данные в html файл из json.
Есть index.html в котором описана форма для бронирования. Внутри после Valitse aikaa за комментирована часть кода, если раз комментировать то появиться возможность выбрать время с помощью радио кнопок.
Мне надо сделать так что бы возможность выбора времени была импортирована из ajat.json. Этот документ находиться в том же директории виртуального сервера XAMPP установленного на моем компьютере.
Как понимаю сначала надо подключить Jquery что и сделал.

Потом с помощью  скрипта пытаюсь получить данные из ajat.json.
К сожалению, не получается.
Файлы находятся в  XAMPP в папке htdocs – sites – site.loc в этой папке три документа index.html​, ajat.json и папка CSS.
Если кто знает подскажите, пожалуйста,.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="fi">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS ensin -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Sitten oma css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ajanvaraus.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Ajanvaraus</title>
    

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid sinitaus">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Tervetuloa varaamaan äikä</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <form>
    <div class="container valkotaus">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sposti">Sähköposti</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="sposti" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="aiheet">Valitse aihe:</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="aiheet" name="aiheet">
          <option value="m15">15 min</option>
          <option value="m30">30 min</option>
          <option value="m45">45 min</option>             
        </select>
        </div>
            
        <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="paikka">Valitse paikka:</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="paikka" name="paikka">
          <option value="p1">Paikka 1</option>
          <option value="p2">Paikka 2</option>            
        </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="paiva">Valitse päivä:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" id="paiva" name="paiva" required>
        </div>
        
        <div id="vapaatAjat">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
        <script>    
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log("haa");
                    
                    $.getJSON("ajat.json", function(response){
                        
                            $(response.ajat).each(function(index, arvo) {
                                var teksti = "<br><input type='radio' name='aika' value='"+(arvo.aika)+
                                "'> "+arvo.aika+"</input>";
                                console.log(teksti);
                                $("#vapaatAjat").append($(teksti));
                    });                     
                });
                });
        </script>   
            
            Valitse aika:
            
            <!--<div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="aika" id="aika10" value="12:00" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="aika10">
                12:00
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="aika" id="aika11" value="12:30">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="aika11">
                12:30
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="aika" id="aika12" value="12:30">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="aika12">
                14:30
              </label>
            </div>
            </div>-->
            
            
        </div>
        
        <button id="nappi" class="btn btn-primary">Lähetä</button>
    </div>
    
    </form>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ajat.json

```
{
    "ajat": [{
            "aika": "15.00"
        },
        {
            "aika": "16.00"
        },
        {
            "aika": "17.00"
        },
        {
            "aika": "17.30"
        },
        {
            "aika": "18.00"
        }
    ]    
}
```